# Assimp - How to access armature which is separate from mesh?

Tags: assimp, skeletal-animation, skeletal-mesh

I'm using Assimp to import an animated FBX file. My problem is that the armature within the scene exists independently to the 11 separate mesh which share that same joint data. Until now I've been retrieving the bone data as I iterate over the mesh but this won't discover the complete armature in cases such as this. All the learning material I can find is doing it the same way.

```
for (uint i = 0 ; i < pMesh->mNumBones ; i++) {
    string BoneName(pMesh->mBones[i]->mName.data);
```

This is an overview of the data within the file. The shotgun meshes are not skinned to a bone hierarchy, instead they have animated transforms which are interpreted as bones, so they do not share any bones with the arms skeleton.

**How can I access the complete armature using Assimp to import the model?**

[image]